Is there a way to add backdrop filter and a layer blur together?
I need something like this.
There's is a div on the background, it blurs the background using that blurs the image using a background filter blur.
But I also want the div to have a layer blur too so it looks like its fading off and doesn't look like it ends abruptly.
Now note, I know that filter and backdrop filter don't work well together, which is exactly why I'm looking for a solution.
I tried just doing a background filter to blur the background and applied a linear gradient but that didn't work either.

Here's a link:
https://codepen.io/asaadmahmood/pen/KKObdgy
<div class="background-container">
  <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>

.background-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1709348369087-38c05ee1a7f9?q=80&w=3774&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Overlay with backdrop and layer blur */
.overlay {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* Background blur */
  filter: blur(10px); /* Layer blur */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Text styling */
.footer {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 5;
}


Since filter and backdrop-filter don't stack well, using a semi-transparent gradient  overlay provides the fading effect without using an additional filter property.
see snippet for example:


.background-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1709348369087-38c05ee1a7f9?q=80&w=3774&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* bg blur */
  }

  /* Pseudo-element for fading effect */
  .overlay::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ); /* Fading gradient */
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  /* Text styling */
  .footer {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
  }
<div class="background-container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="footer">This is a footer</div>
</div>



Just some modifications applied here hope this helps.

if it helps mark as answered.

If only it was that easy. Obviously that won't work.

Modified hope this is the initial requirement!

Bro, please see your own screenshot above, there is a really sharp cut on the div and it doesn't really blend or spread...
